# Yii2 before save check if attributes are changed

Tags: php, model, yii2

I want to check if some attributes in my model are changed in `beforeSave()` method according to data stored in database.

Is there some best practice to check if model has changed?

My goal si to make history. If some attribute changes, I save a copy into `model_history` table.

Comment: In beforeSave() you could try to check `dirtyAttributes` model attribute: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#$dirtyAttributes-detail

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually do that using `afterSave()`.

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if(!$insert) {
        // your code here like $changedAttributes['myField'];
    }
}
```

`$changedAttributes` saves the values of the attributes that were changed.

Answer (score 16):

You need to check for **dirty attributes**

You can call `yii\db\ActiveRecord::getDirtyAttributes()` to get the attributes that are currently dirty.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#dirty-attributes

Answer (score 8):

You must be careful,by use dirtyAttributes property because yii, consider the following:
before  myfield type int =4
after   myfield type string = "4"
if it happens myfield will be into dirtyAttributes automatically.

Other point:
For your dirtyAttributes your fields should be "safeAttributes"  in the scenario where you are going to work, in other way this changes will be ignored

regards