# How do I update a value (adding on to that value) on every form submit?

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii2

I've got a transaction form which, when submitted, stores a 'total_value'. The page then reloads onto the same form so that the user can add some more data. I want the value input to be added to the 'total_value' previously inserted.

Example:
If on first submit value = 10 and on second submit value = 5, then total_value stored should be 15.

This is my code in my controller:

```
$discount = Master::findOne(['id' => $usrM->master_id])->rate_discount;
$tempArray = Yii::$app->request->post('template');
$seat = Yii::$app->request->post('BookingDetails')['seats_count'];
$cost = [];

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

       $sp = Template::findOne(['id'=>$tempArray])->standard_price;
       $seat_cost = $sp * $seat;
       array_push($cost, $seat_cost);
       $sum = array_sum($cost);

       //this is the total cost of all templates with master center discount applied
       $total = $sum - ($sum*($discount/100));

       $model->save();
       Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ebs_booking_transaction SET total_value ='.$total.' WHERE id = '.$trans)->execute();
```

Comment: `SET total_value = total_value + ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yii2's ActiveRecord `beforeUpdate` build-in method & very handy property `dirtyAttributes` for example, to always update the `total_value` whenever an update event happens and the `total` value changed in that update event.

Also see:
[Yii2 before save check if attributes are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495950/yii2-before-save-check-if-attributes-are-changed)

And: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#dirty-attributes